# Question about authentication in API GET call

Tags: api, httr

I'm attempting to access basic food information using the Food Data Central REST API described on the USDA website:

[Food Data Central API Guide](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html#food-search-endpoint)

For this project, I'm making the call using the *httr* (v 1.3.1) package in R.

The documentation for the API call seems pretty good, and provides a few examples; unfortunately, none of these examples utilize R and, since I know very little about API development, I'm unsure how the "content" of the documentation should translate to me.  The documentation provides the following example:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json"

-d '{"generalSearchInput":"Cheddar cheese"}'

-X POST

https://DEMO_KEY@api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search
```

I see a "Content-Type" header and a body in which the string "Cheddar cheese" is bring provided to a parameter called *generalSearchInput*.  It also appears I need to replace the 'DEMO_KEY' string with my own API key.

I would rather not share my own API key but [it's painless to request one](https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-key-signup.html) (click link, enter name/email, get a key seconds later, don't even have to confirm email).

Below s my attempt to duplicate this call in the *httr* package:

```
httr::POST(url = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search", 
           authenticate(user = "<MyAPIKey>", password = "", type = "basic"),
           query = list(generalSearchInput = "Cheddar cheese",
           encode = "json")

)
```

With the following response:

```
Response [https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search]
  Date: 2019-10-10 20:34
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 141 B
{
  "error": {
    "code": "API_KEY_INVALID",
    "message": "An invalid api_key was supplied. Get one at https://api.nal.usda.gov:443"
  }
```

Which is perhaps not surprising.  I'm stuck on a few issues:

How do I correctly pass my API key to the call? I've attempted to do so using basic HTTP authentication [as described on the api.data.gov website documentation](https://api.data.gov/docs/api-key/) (i.e., key as username and an empty password) but I don't think I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: Thanks to @Kenna I've updated my API call.  It now appears that the host is receiving and recognizing the request, although it still does not recognize the way in which I'm passing my API key.  I've put in an updated error message to demonstrate the new result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html), you can include JSON data in the body of the POST request in this way:

```
httr::POST(
    url = "https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/search", 
    authenticate(user = "<MyAPIKey>", password = "", type = "basic"),
    body = list(generalSearchInput = "Cheddar cheese"),
    encode = "json"
)
```

Comment: Thank you; this answers part of my question about passing the parameters to the host but for someone reason they still don't like the way I'm passing my API key...question has been updated to demonstrate.  Thanks again!

Comment: I retract my previous statement!  Apparently the API key I requested was no longer valid (as implied by the updated error message...!)  Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still working on this, but this code I found from someone on Github might help. It has been working for me. You just need to fill in the apiKey and a particular foodID.

import requests
import json
import pandas as pd #if you want to add the response to a dataframe to make it easier to work with (that code not shown here)

apiKey = ''

foodID = ''

def nutrient_API(apiKey, foodID):
    #calls get api and json load
    api_resp = json.loads(requests.get('https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/' + foodID + '?api_key=' + apiKey).text)
    #only return nutrition information
    api_nutrients = api_resp['foodNutrients']
    #first entry is its description, foodID, and database entry type
    nutrientDict = {"FoodID": [api_resp['description'],foodID, api_resp['dataType']]}

```
for items in api_nutrients:
    if 'amount' in items:
        #each entry includes nutrient name, nutrient id, amount, and its respective unit
        nutrientDict.update({(items['nutrient']['name']): [(items['nutrient']['id']),
            (items['amount']),(items['nutrient']['unitName'])]})
    #print(nutrientDict)
return(nutrientDict)
```